# htaccess redirect keeps looping rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to set up a simple redirect for the root of my subdomain to a subfolder in the same subdomain.

Basically I'm trying to get a redirect

`backlight.mydomain.com`

to

`backlight.mydomain.com/backlight/client-response`

Its only the root of the subdomain I need redirected, but I'm pretty sure thats already happening.

Problem is that my code keeps redirecting so what I'm actually getting is:

`http://backlight.mydomain.com/backlight/client-response/backlight/client-response/backlight/client-response/backlight/client-response/backlight/client-response.....`

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} backlight\.vejbyfoto\.dk [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://backlight.vejbyfoto.dk/backlight/client-response [L,R=301]
```

I put the htaccess in the subdomain root directory, which I'm guessing is right?

Can anyone tell where my code is wrong?

Comment: Try without the second RewriteCond, and simply match `^$` (“empty” path component, the leading slash has already been stripped away at this time when configured in htaccess context) in the RewriteRule pattern. (And the leading dot in the rewrite target seems out of place.)

Comment: Thanks! 

Well now I'm arriving at the right url, but now there is an error message saying: "This page isn’t working, backlight.mydomain.com/backlight/client-response redirected too many times". And yeah, the leading dot was a typo.

Comment: Wait, now the rewrite is affecting all urls on my subdomain. It's only supposed to be the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out on my own. It's not really a complex dilemma or anything, I'm just really clueless when it comes to .htaccess and redirect syntax.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^backlight\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://backlight.mydomain.com/backlight/client-response/ [L,R=301]
```

So that's that.